# My own code vs library

Tags: java

This is kind of unusual question for developers but for some reason i want to post it here and hope to get adequate answer.

Here is a simple example:

I wrote a java function that calculates distance between two geo points. The function is not more than 50 lines of code. I decided to download a source code from ibm that does the same thing but when i opened it i saw that it looks very complicated and is almost thousand lines of code.

What kind of people write such source code? Are they just very good programmers? Should i use their source code or my own?

I have noticed this kind of thing lots of times and i from time to time i start to wonder if it is just me who do not know how exactly to program or maybe i am wrong?

Do you guys have the same kind of feeling when you browse throught some other peoples source code?

Comment: You should definitely look at the FAQ.
Flagged as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: There code will most likely support many many more use cases then yours. It will also be tested, so that is a plus, but dont assume it was written by very good developers

Comment: Can you give a link to the code? Maybe then we can answer concretely.

Comment: The quality of a piece of code is not measured in number of lines. Actually, removing lines while doing the same thing is often a good thing.

Comment: for example java.util.Logger uses lots of classes where each one of them uses even more so it is almost impossible to see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

The code you found, does it do the exact same calculation? Perhaps it takes into account some edge cases you didn't think of, or uses an algorithm that has better numerical stability, lower asymptotic complexity, or is written to take advantage of branch prediction or CPU caches. Or it could be just over-engineered.

Remember the saying: "For every complex problem there is a solution that is simple, elegant, and wrong." If you are dealing with numerical software, even the most basic problems like [adding a bunch of numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) can turn out to be surprisingly complex.